# How to programmatically fire click event on specific grid row in JqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a scenario where I have several jqgrids. Clicking row in one grid is reloading the other. Now I need to do this programatically. I want to fire rowclick event when some other event fires (for example dialog onclose - it doesn't really matter what event). Important is a have the grid row number as a parameter available. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [setSelection](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method to select the row. See [the small demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectRow.htm) which I wrote for you to demonstrate this.

Comment: jQuery(table).jqGrid('setSelection', rowNum, true); does the trick thanx for quick reply and nice example.